# JavaFX autoresize & auto-position

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `VBox` which contains `Pane`s. Over the `VBox`, I want to show another element (currently I use a `Pane`). This element has to overlay multiple `Pane`s in the `VBox`, so I put this element together with the `VBox` inside an `AnchorPane`. The complete structure looks like this:

```
HBox
  VBox
    Label   <--- "Friday"
    AnchorPane
      VBox   <--- the VBox with Panes
        Pane
        ...
      Pane   <--- the Pane over the VBox  (red in images)
```

The problem is that when I resize the window, the red `Pane` does not resize nor change its position.

**Normal size**:

[image: normal]

**Small size**:

[image: small]

I want the red `Pane` to start at the same line (3rd) and be of the same *relative* size.

I tried binding the `Pane`'s `prefWidthProperty` and `prefHeightProperty` to its parent (`AnchorPane`). This works for auto-resizing.

For auto-positioning, I have tried to bind the `layoutX|Y` properties, which didn't work, because these are set by the system and I get exception "Bound value cannot be set". So I tried to make the `Pane` unmanaged, which in turn broke the auto-resize, since in unmanaged nodes, changes in preferred properties have no effect. I thought of binding `widthProperty` and `heightProperty` to the parent's properties, but these are read-only.

Comment: You can implement the logic of the required offset with bindings, to keep things in sync.

Comment: What bindings? Where do I set them?

Comment: Didn't see your edit when i typed it. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a `GridPane` for functionality like this. You can add multiple nodes to the same cell(s) in the grid (the ones added last will appear on top in z-order). A `GridPane` allows maximum flexibility for layout. Here's an example: note that there's a lot of styling here that I just hard-coded for brevity, but in a real app you should move this to an external stylesheet (you can do the same with the max sizes, etc):

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CalendarExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane calendar = new GridPane();

        // headers:
        for (DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.MONDAY ; dayOfWeek.getValue() <= DayOfWeek.FRIDAY.getValue(); 
                dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.of(dayOfWeek.getValue() + 1) ) {

            Label label = new Label(dayOfWeek.toString());
            label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            label.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black, darkgray; -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 1 ;"); 
            calendar.add(label, dayOfWeek.getValue(), 0);
        }

        DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm");

        int rowCount = 0 ;

        for (LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(8, 0); time.isBefore(LocalTime.of(17, 0)); time=time.plusMinutes(30)) {
            rowCount++ ;
            Label label = new Label(timeFormatter.format(time));
            label.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            String color = rowCount % 2 == 0 ? "darkgray" : "lightgray" ;
            label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black, "+color+"; -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 1;");           
            calendar.add(label, 0, rowCount);
        }

        // cells:

        for (int x = 1 ; x <= 5; x++) {
            for (int y = 1 ; y <= rowCount; y++) {
                Region region = new Region();
                String color = y % 2 == 0 ? "darkgray" : "lightgray" ;
                region.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black, "+color+"; -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 1 ;");
                calendar.add(region, x, y);
            }
        }

        // Column constraints:
        for (int x = 0 ; x <= 5 ; x++) {
            ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
            cc.setPercentWidth(100.0 / 6);
            cc.setFillWidth(true);
            calendar.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        }

        // row constraints:
        for (int y = 0 ; y <= rowCount; y++) {
            RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
            rc.setPercentHeight(100.0 / (rowCount+1));
            rc.setFillHeight(true);
            calendar.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
        }

        // Example appointment block:

        DayOfWeek appointmentDay = DayOfWeek.FRIDAY ;
        LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.of(10, 0);
        LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.of(13, 0);

        String appointmentText = "Fridays need really long coffee breaks";
        Label appointment = new Label(appointmentText);
        appointment.setTooltip(new Tooltip(appointmentText));
        appointment.setWrapText(true);
        appointment.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

        appointment.setStyle("-fx-background: red; -fx-background-color: -fx-background; " );
        GridPane.setMargin(appointment, new Insets(2, 5, 2, 2));


        Scene scene = new Scene(calendar, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

This also behaves as needed when the window is resized:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed! Another question that you might know the answer to: is it possible to justify hours in the first column by the column (":") ?

Comment: @kyrill I can't think of an easy way to do that. One idea that comes to mind is to use a `GridPane` in each cell in that column with a single row and three columns. Use column constraints to make the first and last columns have `hgrow` set to `ALWAYS` and the middle column set to `NEVER`; set the `halignment` for the first columns to `RIGHT` and for the third column to `LEFT`. Then put a label in each cell: hours, then `":"`, then minutes. That would do it, but it's a bit convoluted.

Comment: @kyrill Also, please mark the answer as correct if it solves the problem: it will make it easier for other users to find it. (I notice you haven't marked any answers as correct yet...).

Comment: Yes, it's not worth the trouble. One more thing: is there an easy way to make `GridPane` cell span, say, three and a half rows? Or do they always span entire rows and columns?

Comment: @kyrill The row and column spans are integers. You could achieve minute-level precision by making a large number of rows (one per minute) and having the row headers (time), and "cells", span multiple rows (row span would be 30 in my example). Then the row span for the "appointment" would be the number of minutes. That should work pretty easily.

Comment: @James_D From your post it seems GridPane 1x1 can behave like StackPane? Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

`width` and `height` properties may be readonly, but you can assign the prefered sizes and use `autosize`.

**Example**

The following code makes the overlay start at 50% height and have a height of 1/3 of the `VBox` height:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Region region1 = new Region();
    VBox.setVgrow(region1, Priority.ALWAYS);
    region1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

    Region region2 = new Region();
    VBox.setVgrow(region2, Priority.ALWAYS);
    region2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lime;");

    Region regionOverlay = new Region();
    regionOverlay.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
    regionOverlay.setManaged(false);

    VBox root = new VBox(region1, region2, regionOverlay);
    root.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        regionOverlay.setPrefSize(newValue.getWidth() - 20, newValue.getHeight() / 3);
        regionOverlay.setLayoutX(10);
        regionOverlay.setLayoutY(newValue.getHeight() / 2);
        regionOverlay.autosize();
    });

    root.setPrefSize(400, 400);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a red rectangle, i'd advise you to use the `Rectangle` shape instead of panes. This allows you to bind its widths and heights explicitly.

Comment: Actually I'm not quite sure I can use a `Rectangle`, since in the `Pane` will contain some text (a `Label` or something). I solved it using listeners on the parent. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @kyrill If you're using listeners to manage layout, there's almost certainly a better way. Use a layout pane of some kind that does this for you.

Comment: Of what kind? I'm quite new to JavaFX, so I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: @kyrill Posted an answer with an example you can experiment with. A `GridPane` is probably what you need here.